# Expression « gouteux en diable »

Tags: sens, expressions

J'ai trouvé l'expression

> goûteux en diable

dans un guide français. Que signifie-t-elle exactement ? Y a-t-il un rapport avec le piment ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le petit Robert vient à la rescousse :

> - Gouteux : qui a beaucoup de goût
> - En diable : très, terriblement

Il ne vous reste plus qu'à faire *l'assemblage* (terme viticole qui assure le mélange harmonieux de différents cépages avant la mise en bouteille des grands crus, ou la mise en vieillissement dans les *[foudres](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foudre_%28r%C3%A9cipient%29)* de cognac).